# different output when writing a file

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a binary file, for this I am using

```
namespace BinaryStream
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"c:\happybirthday.txt";
            using (BinaryWriter binWriter =
    new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                string name = "Sachin";
                string wishes = "happy birthday";

                binWriter.Write(name.ToCharArray());
                binWriter.Write(wishes.ToCharArray());
            }



        }
    }
}
```

if binWriter.Writer(name) is used the file contains some special characters. But if i convert the string to chararray and write to file , the file contains the normal text(without any special characters).

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because one is writing binary and the other is a longhand way of writing plain text? Why are you using a binary writer in this case?

Comment: File has two parts 1. header- which contains the data which human readable format and other is the body which contains the binary data. Intention is to use one writer which can do this. If possible can u suggest the alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in writing string vs. char array with System.IO.BinaryWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014727/difference-in-writing-string-vs-char-array-with-system-io-binarywriter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Write(string)` overload is length prefixed:

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx

> A length-prefixed string represents the string length by prefixing to
>   the string a single byte or word that contains the length of that
>   string. This method first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7
>   encoded unsigned integer, and then writes that many characters to the
>   stream by using the BinaryWriter instance's current encoding.

Whereas `Write(char[])` is not. That extra information will show up as weird data when opened with text viewing.

The reason for this is obvious when looking at read behaviour. `BinaryReader.ReadChars` needs to be told how many chars to read, while `BinaryReader.ReadString` works it out by looking at the length prefix.

**Edit:** Possible duplicate, extra info anyway: [Difference in writing string vs. char array with System.IO.BinaryWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014727/difference-in-writing-string-vs-char-array-with-system-io-binarywriter)

Answer (score 1):

BinaryWriter.Write(string) writes first length and then writes the string in file. So you found the special char in file that is pointing to length of that string.

Msdn description for this function:

A length-prefixed string represents the string length by prefixing to the string a single byte or word that contains the length of that string. This method first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer, and then writes that many characters to the stream by using the BinaryWriter instance's current encoding.